# When running matplotlib.pyplot.savefig in a subprocess, what can cause a deadlock or a freeze?

Tags: python, matplotlib, multiprocessing

In order to speed things up in a scientific computing software written in Python, I want to offload the construction and saving of intermediate figures to subprocesses using a `multiprocessing.Pool()`.

The implementation is straightforward.

Most of the time it works fine but sometimes the subprocesses go into a deadlock and my program freezes.

I am running python on a UNIX machine.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a bunch of days not knowing what to google or what the issue could be and finally found that blog post : [forking vs spawn](https://britishgeologicalsurvey.github.io/science/python-forking-vs-spawn/).

This QA is really here to have it better referenced and easier to find.

It boils down to the fact that matplotlib is not thread safe, and forking isn't either. So when running matplotlib methods in a subprocess, please make sure this subprocess is created using the `spawn` context.